# How to create a testers group in play console using work email

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to create an internal test group for our next  Android app release, using play store "Manage-Testers" link. but when I try to add my colleagues'  office email address I'm getting this error

```
Invalid email address found - fname.lname@xyz.com Users need a Google Account (@gmail.com) or a Google Apps account to join a test.
```

How can I create test group using work email address ?

Documentation say:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Email requirements: Users need a Google Account (@gmail.com) or a G Suite account to join a test.

What is G Suite Account?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you will need to provide the gmail id. The gmail id is not only the email address, it represents your whole Google account including the one used in the play store.

So the testers can test your app only if you have added their gmail account used by them in their play store app.

Comment: so they have to use the same email address configured on the play store if I do a closed alpha test and if the user forwards the app invitation email or the link to someone else can he download the app and use it?

Comment: No other people cannot download the app even with the link. Only people whose gmail account you've listed as test users can accept the invitation anc download the app.

Comment: then only option available for me to use the Hockey app and send the link work email, so the user should be able to download the app and play with it, do you know what is G Suite Account mean?

Comment: I don't know. What is the problem with using their gmail accounts?

Comment: For me, the confusion is security. When a person leaves a company, the company cannot block access to that user by just disabling their corporate email account anymore. Thus feels less secure, unless people are aware.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Gmail as the Google Play Store only allow an email from Gmail. G Suite Account is the account for the version of Google cloud from Google for the business including Gmail, Docs, Drive and Calendar. You can found the information about the G Suite Account from [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/)

After you've added the people to the tester list, they will receive the invitation and can view the link to your app in the Google Play Store. The app will be private and can be used by the tester only.